# Excel formula that arranges rows in a column based on the rows arrangement from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 sheet in excel 2010s: In the 1st Sheet I have all the data and a 2nd sheet where based on the ID's entered(TP) on column `A-Sheet2` the formula returns rows from Sheet1.

It looks like this:
[image: sheet1]
[image: sheet2]

Formula used : `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$E1),IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!E1),"",Sheet1!E1),"")`

As it can be seen, in column A from Sheet2 the ID's entered are in a specific order (they are copied from another excel file). Is there a formula that arranges the findings from Sheet2 (column F,G,H) in the same line with Id's from column A-Sheet2?

In the end it should look like:
[image: final]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this index match match formula:

```
=IF($A4="","-",INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$G$11,MATCH(Sheet2!$A4,Sheet1!$E$1:$E$11,0),MATCH(Sheet2!E$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$1,0)))
```

Paste that into sheet2, cell E5, then copy that cell to E5:H12.

The function focuses on the table in sheet1. Change the coordinates `$A$1:$G$11` if your sheet1 table is bigger. The function matches the sheet2 column A value to a row in column E in the table, and then matches the sheet2 row 1 heading to a column in row 1 of the table, "indexing" a single result. The formula is copyable to any row or column on sheet2. Note that column headings must be spelled the same way as the sheet1 column headings.

Comment: David,  you have my gratitude:) , you helped me a lot with this; it saves me a lot of time at work. 
Have a wonderful week David.
Also, I have to thank this "forum" for the help.
All the best!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Bogdan! Really glad I helped. Please would you "tick" the answer to mark it as accepted? Then hopefully it'll help others who search for the same problem.